# angular 2 seed referencing node modules such as ng2-responsive

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, systemjs, angular2-seed

While I'm loving Angular 2 in all other respects, I'm finding the supporting infrastructure challenging, particularly when it comes to how to properly reference node modules in my angular2-seed projects.

I've successfully installed ng2-responsive so that it is finding it in app.module.ts:

```
import { ResponsiveModule } from 'ng2-responsive';
```

by adding this:

```
map: {
    'ng2-responsive': 'node_modules/ng2-responsive',
},
packages: {
    'ng2-responsive': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
}
```

to seed.config.ts under SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV

but, I'm now getting:

```
[...]node_modules/ng2-responsive/index.d.ts(1,90): error TS2307: Cannot find module './bootstrap/bootstrap-directives'
```

when it attempts to run build.dev.js after I run npm start, and the same for the other directives referenced in ng2-responsive's index.d.ts...presumably because they're referenced like this:

```
import { XL, LG, MD, SM, XS, ShowItBootstrap, HideItBootstrap, ResponsiveSizeInfo } from './bootstrap/bootstrap-directives';
```

and that path is relative to index.d.ts, not where the it's currently being run from.

Any ideas how I tell build.dev.js to look for these where they actually exist?

Many thanks

Comment: Not sure if this will help you. I haven't used this particular library. What version of Angular are you using?
Also, try this:  main: 'index.js' (without the "./")

Comment: Thanks @BoyanKostadinov. God idea but, sadly, that doesn't help - same errors. I'm using angular2-seed and npm list tells me I'm using Angular 2.1.1

Comment: I'll get angular2 seed and see what it takes to get this working. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Thanks @BoyanKostadinov, that's an incredibly kind offer but it looks as if it may actually be a problem with ng2-responsive, rather than my [lack of!] understanding of systemjs: https://github.com/ManuCutillas/ng2-responsive/issues/45 so maybe worth waiting to see what the module author comes up with. Thanks again.

Comment: Good to know! I think he just fixed it in 6.1. You can always fork the repository and fix it yourself too.

Comment: @theotherdy, Any fix? I have the same issue.

Comment: @ChrisFremgen - that bug fix sorted it for me I'm afraid. However, with every new node module I add, I have new problems with getting it recognised and none of them seem to work in the same way e.g for ng2-charts, I had to add refer to it in project.config.ts: this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES = [
      ...this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES,
      {src: 'ng2-charts/*.js', inject: 'libs'}, whereas angular2-material is added under paths: like this: '@angular/material': 'node_modules/@angular/material/material.umd.js',....I'm sure there's a logical explanation...but I have no idea what it is!